# Getting reliable renders on Matlab R2014b+ (HG2)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, rasterizing, pixel-perfect, matlab-hg2

I can't manage to make Matlab new graphics engine (HG2) display lines and markers in a *reliable* way, meaning a way that is identically displayed / rendered everywhere in the axes / screen.

To demonstrate the issue, I've coded a simple script (see end of post) and compared results under R2014a (using Matlab old HG1 engine) versus R2016b (thus with Matlab new HG2 engine), both for the *painters* and *opengl* renderers.

(You may note in the script that I've tried to deactivate any kind of HG2 smoothing I was aware of. Though this does alter things somewhat, the general problematic behaviors described happen whether smoothing is deactivated or not.)

[image: view of graphs]

(I'm afraid SO is resizing the image which defeats the point, [so here is a direct link to the image itself](https://image.ibb.co/nNcKhe/Renderers.png))

- R2014a (HG1) & painters renderer : if you zoom in the image, you can check that every marker is pixel-perfect - they're all absolutely identical no matter where they've been drawn. Each green line is exactly 1 pixel wide.
- R2014a (HG1) & opengl renderer : each green line is exactly 1 pixel wide, but markers are not displayed/drawned identical to one another.
- R2016b (HG2) & painters renderer : strangely, similar result as for HG1 & opengl. Lines are the correct width (displayed a bit different than in HG1 but at least they're being consistent), but markers differ throughout the axes.
- R2016b (HG2) & opengl renderer : markers are all identical (although I like them less, that's a subjective issue, the important point is that they're all identical), but you can see the three green lines are NOT all the expected width of 1 pixel : the top and bottom one are 2 pixels wide, only the middle one has been drawn with a width of 1 pixel.

Any idea on how to make any of the two renderers behave correctly (ie, draw the same thing no matter where its in the image) in HG2 ?

Other points of note :

- I'd prefer to use opengl if possible, as for some reason, painters seems awfully slow (at least camera control) for even 'reasonable' numbers of data points (ie thousands) with HG2. Unless of course you *also* know how to make painters in HG2 as fast as it was in HG1.
- While the test code is simple, I actually need to use this in a very elaborate GUI (custom uimenu, uicontrols, panels, callbacks, etc). While I didn't know this could matter, apparently and for example, the potential solution of using a uifigure instead of a figure is not available to me.
- For information, this is what I get when I type `opengl('info')` :

In Matlab R2014a :

```
Version         = 4.0.0 - Build 9.18.10.3131
Vendor          = Intel
Renderer        = Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
MaxTextureSize  = 8192
Visual          = 05 (RGB 32 bits(08 08 08 08) zdepth 24, Hardware Accelerated, Opengl, Double Buffered, Window)
Software        = false
# of Extensions = 139

Driver Bug Workarounds:
OpenGLBitmapZbufferBug    = 0
OpenGLWobbleTesselatorBug = 0
OpenGLLineSmoothingBug    = 0
OpenGLDockingBug          = 0
OpenGLClippedImageBug     = 0
OpenGLEraseModeBug        = 0
```

In Matlab R2016b :

```
                          Version: '1.1.0'
                           Vendor: 'Microsoft Corporation'
                         Renderer: 'GDI Generic'
                   MaxTextureSize: 1024
                           Visual: 'Visual 0x24, (RGB 24 bits (8 8 8), Z depth 16 bits, Software, Single buffer, Antialias 0 samples)'
                         Software: 'true'
             HardwareSupportLevel: 'none (known graphics driver issues)'
        SupportsGraphicsSmoothing: 0
    SupportsDepthPeelTransparency: 0
       SupportsAlignVertexCenters: 0
                       Extensions: {3×1 cell}
               MaxFrameBufferSize: 0
```

The sample code used was :

```
rng(0)
data=rand(1,30);

DSKS=sort(data);

renderer='painters';
%renderer='opengl';

Name=[version ' - ' renderer];
try close(Name);end; %#ok<TRYNC>
h=figure('Name',Name,'NumberTitle','off');

if ~verLessThan('matlab','8.4.0')
    set(gcf,'GraphicsSmoothing','off','DefaultTextFontSmoothing','off','DefaultAxesFontSmoothing','off')
end

set(gcf,'Renderer',renderer)

plot(DSKS,100*(1:length(DSKS))/length(DSKS),...
    'Color','k','LineStyle','none','Marker','x','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',8);
hold on

ZEROX=0;ZEROY=0;
typique=0.5;
if ~isempty(typique)
    plot([typique typique],[ZEROY 100],'r--','LineWidth',2)
end

plot([0 0],[0 100],'--','Color',0.7*[1 1 1],'LineWidth',2)

XL=get(gca,'XLim');XL2=[XL(1) max(XL(2),1)];

plot(XL2,[50 50],'r--','LineWidth',2)
plot(XL2,[68.27 68.27],'g--','LineWidth',1);
plot(XL2,[95.45 95.45],'g--','LineWidth',1);
plot(XL2,[99.73 99.73],'g--','LineWidth',1);
hold on

grid on

title(Name,'FontWeight','bold')
```

Comment: "You may note in the script that I've tried to deactivate any kind of HG2 smoothing I was aware of." Why? The anti-aliasing is what allows the rendering to be consistent independent of sub-pixel shifts.  You create these inconsistencies by turning it off.

Comment: @CrisLuengo : no, I didn't. Try it without and you'll notice similar problems. But I'll edit the main text to address this.

Comment: I don't see this with anti-aliasing turned on, but it might be because I use a high-resolution display and all lines are several pixels thick. One solution for you, if you want to generate pixel-perfect figures (rather than export them as vector graphics) is to place things at integer pixel locations. I could write up an answer showing how to do this if you are interested. But in general I would suggest to ignore these things and pay attention to the exported vector drawings.

Comment: Would it be correct to add [tag:rasterizing] and [tag:pixel-perfect] to this question? I understand your question, but I'm not sure what is the purpose behind your request - are you exporting these images in some non-vector format and afraid they might misrepresent something, or does it subjectively bother you when you're looking at them?

Comment: @Dev-iL : thanks for the tag suggestions. I've just added them, hopefully they apply. Regarding your queston, it's first and foremost because this visual inconsistency bothers me to no end.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want to plot a "high number of lines/dots", and also that you're using R2016b - so why not try a [`uifigure`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uifigure.html)? Here's an example:

```
rng(0)
data = rand(1,30);
DSKS = sort(data);

hF  = uifigure('Name', version, 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'Visible','off');
hAx = uiaxes( hF, 'Position', hF.Position .* [0 0 1 1] );

plot(hAx, DSKS, 100*(1:numel(DSKS))./numel(DSKS),...
     'Color' ,'k', 'LineStyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'x',...
     'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 8);

hold(hAx,'on');

ZEROX = 0; ZEROY = 0;
typique = 0.5;
plot(hAx, typique*[1 1], [ZEROY 100], 'r--', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(hAx, [ZEROX ZEROX], [ZEROY 100], '--',  'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 0.7*[1 1 1]);

XL = hAx.XLim; XL2 = [XL(1) max(XL(2),1)];
plot(hAx, XL2, [50 50],      'r--', 'LineWidth', 2)
plot(hAx, XL2, [68.27 68.27],'g--', 'LineWidth', 1);
plot(hAx, XL2, [95.45 95.45],'g--', 'LineWidth', 1);
plot(hAx, XL2, [99.73 99.73],'g--', 'LineWidth', 1);

grid(hAx,'on');

title(hAx,Name,'FontWeight','bold');
hF.Visible = 'on';
```

Which gives:

[image: Regular size]

For comparison, see what happens (to line thickness etc.) when the figure is maximized (click for full size):

[image: Enlarged]

I think that pixel-perfectness in terms of line widths comes down to rasterization, which is not an issue if you're exporting vector graphics (e.g. `.emf` or `.eps`). In any case, I would suggest the [`export_fig`](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/) utility, as it greatly helps in achieving consistent exports.

You might notice that I did not set a renderer, since a `uifigure` is essentially a web page, and does not support this setting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. I'm not sure at all I can use a uifigure though, as the axes are actually inside a quite complex GUI (with tabs, lots of controls and callbacks, custom menus...), which of course the test script was not replicating as it was irrelevant until your answer :). I'll have to check uifigure limitations (if any) and whether I could "just" make this whole GUI a uifigure instead of a figure.

Comment: You should keep in mind that uifigures are in very active development, and they had their capabilities expanded considerably in recent releases (because they were quite limited when they were introduced), so updating MATLAB might be required to get everything working in the new system. Note that there's also an [automated migration tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66087) provided by TMW. Regarding your new requirements that were revealed just now: I probably wouldn't have written this answer seeing how difficult it might be to integrate into an existing project.

Comment: OK, I have just checked, and unfortunately it seem uifigures are hugely limited (no camera control, no callbacks, no uicontrol, no uimenus). So that's unfortunately absolutely no-no for me. I'll add this limitation to main question.

Comment: @ParkerLewis I have to ask - within the confines of the discussed example, does the result of this approach address your needs?

Comment: it bothers me a bit that setting LineWidth to 1 does not lead to a 1 pixel wide line (green lines), but at least the behavior seems to be consistent within each picture, so I could settle for such a result.

Comment: @ParkerLewis `LineWidth` is measured in "points", not in "pixels", so generally it _shouldn't_ work the way you want (1 point equals 1/72 inch). How inches map to pixels depends on your display, resolution etc.

Comment: You're totally right, I misspoke. The conclusion is the same though -- I would be ok with such a result.